# Set ViewModel data value from inside timeout doesn't update the View

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I need to update my `ViewModel` data from inside a `setTimeout` callback function, but it doesn't work. It looks like I'm running into a problem similar to what happens when I need to update data value in Angular outside Angular and then need to call `$scope.apply()`, but in ExtJS' way.

Here's the code:

```
Ext.define('Web.view.taskbar.clock.ClockController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.taskbar-clock',

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        // this works
        var time = new Date();
        me.getViewModel().data.time = time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':' + time.getSeconds(); 

        // this doesn't work
        var timer = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var time = new Date();
                me.getViewModel().data.time = time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':' + time.getSeconds(); 
                timer();
            }, 1000);
        };
        timer();
    }
});
```

**Edit:** 
Updated working code

```
Ext.define('Web.view.taskbar.clock.ClockController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.taskbar-clock',

    init: function() {
        var vm = this.getViewModel();

        var timer = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var time = new Date();
                vm.set('time', time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':' + time.getSeconds()); 
                timer();
            }, 1000);
        }
        timer();
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: ExtJS 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the setter method: [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewModel-method-set).

`vm.set('time', 'x');`